# How to figure out permalink for a Google Groups message by email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, mailing-list, google-groups, google-groups-api

I'm building a system on Google Apps where people in a number of offices scan documents to a Google Group email. Currently, these are forwarded to me and I have a Google Apps Script running that looks at each email, copies the attachment to Drive, and adds a link to it on a Site in an structured manner, by fiscal year, office, etc. (all from the email subject line).

My Drive will eventually run out, and my organization refuses to create a separate account for technical reasons, and Groups has unlimited storage. I'm trying to figure out a way for the script to instead figure out the permalink to each message. I've seen Groups messages online that include "To view this discussion on the web visit" links, but can't find a setting to enable that. I've tried looking at the email headers, but can't see anything there either.

Does anyone know of a way to generate links to a Groups message based upon the email contents?

Comment: Another alternative I have is to use the script to forward these emails to another Group, this time with lots of details in the subject line for easy searching. I mainly want to intercept these emails so I can deal with inconsistent and undecipherable subject lines.

Comment: Your organisation could buy more storage for your account http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1726914 it's not that expensive.

Comment: We're trying not to use my account for storage because it's my account, and I was told by the people who manage our Google Apps accounts that I can't get another account.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Unless you can fetch the group page and look for it yourself (screen scraping).

Comment: It's for internal use only, so the Group isn't public. Would UrlFetch services work with that?

Comment: I have never tried this, but probably not.